# Log XML payload when MarshallingMessageConverter is used in Spring Integration's Amqp inboundAdapter

Tags: logging, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have `IntegrationFlow` which listens for AMQP messages and I want to log XML message payload.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(
    Amqp.inboundAdapter(rabbitConnectionFactory, QUEUE)
            .messageConverter(new MarshallingMessageConverter(xmlMarshaller))
)
    .log(INFO, "org.springframework.amqp")
    ...
    .get();
```

When I use `MarshallingMessageConverter` in `Amqp.inboundAdapter()`, then already deserialized object instead of XML payload is logged in `.log()` step

I can get around this problem with default `SimpleMessageConverter` and explicit `.transform()` step.

Is there a way how to log original XML payload and keep using `MarshallingMessageConverter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way is to add a `MessagePostProcessor` into a listener container:

```
Amqp.inboundAdapter(rabbitConnectionFactory, QUEUE)
                        .messageConverter(new MarshallingMessageConverter(xmlMarshaller))
                        .configureContainer(container ->
                                container.afterReceivePostProcessors(message ->
                                        logger.info(new String(message.getBody()))))
```

Another one, of course, is to extend that `MarshallingMessageConverter` and override its `fromMessage(Message message)` to log the body before calling `super.fromMessage()`.